# How to read Json file and use in everywhere as service?

Tags: angular, angular5

I need to create global dictionary with translations in Angular and I want to use this dictionary in each component.
I have created a custom service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import _dictionary from "../assets/js/dictionary.json";

interface IWords {
  [key: string]: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class DictionaryService {
  private dictionary = new Map<string, IWords>();

  constructor() {
    console.log(_dictionary);
  }
}
```

Then I have added this to providers: `@NgModule({  providers: [
    DictionaryService ]});`

As you can see, service uses json file with translations.

Problem is that constructor of service does not work, so I can not see message:

```
console.log(_dictionary);
```

Comment: It should not be necessary to add the DictionaryService in the providers array of @NgModule as you have 'providedIn: "root" ' in the service, it does the same thing. Not sure why you can not see your console.log though.

Comment: Anyway, constructor does not work, I  have removed: `@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})`

Comment: I have figured out, it works only when I use as dependency in component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import json data like this:

```
import * as _dictionary from "../assets/js/dictionary.json";
```

However you can't inject it in your constructor. You could include it your service like this:

```
export class DictionaryService {
  private dictionary = _dictionary;

  constructor() {}
}
```

Side note, for translations there are great tools out there like [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) and [transloco](https://app.gitbook.com/@netbasal/s/transloco) that load json files behind the scenes, and do it really well. I wrote an article explaining how to use them [here](https://medium.com/briebug-blog/internationalizing-your-angular-app-aeebb4e50bfe).

You might need to add `"resolveJsonModule": true` to your compiler options in your tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 2):

To read a JSON file you should use http get and subscribe to it

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
...
this.http.get("../assets/js/dictionary.json").subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Regards